# How to implement a watchdog timer on a Cyclone II FPGA in quartus ii

Tags: fpga, watchdog, quartus, qsys

I need to implement a watchdog timer on my Cyclone II FPGA board.
I have designed the system using QSYS, i need to know what are the next steps to implement and test a watchdog Timer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question seems a bit broad. To get good answers you should consider if you can make it more specific in any way. If you find the answer yourself, rmember to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: You can start with telling us what *"the system"* is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement a watchdog with qsys you can use the "Interval Timer" in library : "Processors and Peripherals" -> "Peripherals" -> "Interval Timer".
Then configure it as a watchdog.

For testing it, it depend to your application. We need more information on your project architecture.